# How to switch between two CSS classes for one control in ASP.Net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
<style type="text/css">
    .CssStyle1   
    { 
       font: 10pt Verdana; 
       font-weight:700;
       color: Green;
    }

    .CssStyle2
    { 
       font: 15pt Times; 
       font-weight:250;
       color: Blue;
    }

</style>


<asp:Label ID="lblEditor" runat="server"
       Text='<%#Eval("Editor") %>'
       Font-Bold="true"/>
```

protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
        { Label lblEditor = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblEditor");

```
        var a= "high";
        if (a == "high")
        {
            lblEditor.CssClass = "CssStyle1";
        }
        else {

            lblEditor.CssClass = "CssStyle2";
        }
```

Here it is changing content according to second but for some occasion I want to use first and for some other I want to use second CSS class. I want to use only one CSS class at a time.

How can I switch between them without button click?

Comment: use jquery toggleclass()..

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: it is not happing with toogle class

Comment: <td style="border:1px; width:100px" align="left">
                           <h3> <asp:Label ID="lblEditor" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("Editor") %>' Font-Bold="true"  CssClass="CssStyle1"/></h3>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                       $( '#lblEditor' ).click(function() {
                         $( this ).toggleClass( "CssStyle2" );
                             });
                       </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put *condition* in code behind to alternate the `CssClass`.

```
if(condition)
   lblEditor.CssClass = "CssStyle1";
else
   lblEditor.CssClass = "CssStyle2";
```

Comment: You hard coded the condition which wont alter classes. What exactly your condition to alter classes

Comment: actually have to apply Punjabi and hindi language according to its category of books which is cmg from database. so first I am tryg to do like this.

Comment: You probably need ItemDataBound event instead of RowCommand. Also use database value cmg to alter the css instead of using hard coded variable "a", http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx